# Jquery sortable serialize gives array of empty objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/ not Jquery UI sortable.

My full code is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/shankardevy/XwkxH/2/

```
jQuery('.draggable').sortable({
  onDrop: function (item, container, _super) {
    console.log($('.draggable').sortable("serialize").get());
    _super(item, container)
  }
})
```

My problem is that in the above code, sortable('serialize') as documented in http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/ is not working for me. It gives me an array of empty objects while I expect the array to contain the `<li>` objects in the order sorted.

Comment: nope. if you expand the array and object in console, you will notice that I have no way to relate the object to the `<li>` element. The objects are not of `<li>`. maybe I'm missing something obvious. I need to get the ids of each of the object in that array.

Answer (score 4):

@sza's answer will work well, still I managed to get it working using the plugin options:

```
jQuery('.draggable').sortable({
  onDrop: function (item, container, _super) {
      console.log(container.el.sortable("serialize").get());
    _super(item, container);
  },
  serialize: function (parent, children, isContainer) {
    return isContainer ? children.join() : parent.attr('id');
  }
});
```

The thing is the the default serialize function wasn't returning the result we expected so I created a custom one much like the one on an example above ("Connected lists with limited drop targets")

Here's the **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/XwkxH/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can get all `<li>` by calling .children() like this

```
var li_list = $('.draggable').children();
```

Comment: @Reigel it is sorted. since the draggable changes the dom and children() are all items from top to bottom.